# Rails Upgrade to 6.1.4.6 Active Record Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, activerecord, rubygems

After upgrading the rails from *"6.1.3.1"* to *"6.1.4.6"* I started to receive a lot of errors of the same kind but in different places in a project (777 tests had errors). Not able to get error trace. The error is always the same:

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`

```
Backend::TasksControllerTest::IndexFilterTest#test_#index_can_filter_on_lead_status:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
  app/models/campaign.rb:133:in `update_schedules'
  test/controllers/backend/tasks_controller_test.rb:137:in `block in <class:IndexFilterTest>'

725) Error:
DeleteModelImportJobTest#test_removes_model_import_and_all_associated_rows:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
  app/models/office/model_import/row.rb:15:in `remove_imported_object'
  app/jobs/delete_model_import_job.rb:6:in `block in perform'
  app/jobs/delete_model_import_job.rb:5:in `perform'
  test/jobs/delete_model_import_job_test.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <class:DeleteModelImportJobTest>'
  test/jobs/delete_model_import_job_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:DeleteModelImportJobTest>'

726) Error:
Backend::Leads::CampaignLeadsControllerTest#test_new_includes_users_from_ponds_as_well_as_team_for_selection:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
  test/controllers/backend/leads/campaign_leads_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:CampaignLeadsControllerTest>'

727) Error:
Backend::Leads::CampaignLeadsControllerTest#test_new_determines_users_without_firepoint_phone_numbers:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
  test/controllers/backend/leads/campaign_leads_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:CampaignLeadsControllerTest>'
```

[Errors Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3tVZ.jpg)

I was trying to debug minitest tests and it seems that all related to ActiveRecord methods raising the error: delete_all!, delete, update_all, update! the transaction, etc. (see screenshots)

[update! error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaRKx.png)

[delete_all error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta9rj.png)

[transaction error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryTM7.png)

Have no idea where to move next and how to fix it, any thoughts on how to proceed and where to look are very appreciated.

Comment: Does the error only show up in the tests or also when you use the tested feature in the application? Did you check your test log file if there is more information available?

Comment: @spickermannIt's also the same for the tested feature in the application. Will check the test log file.  Thank you for the idea to check the test log file.

Answer (score 0):

I run into same exception and what I found was defining scope as
`scope :id, (id) -> { where(id: id }` I had remove the scope and edit my code so everything was fine